# Show that if $ A \in \mathbb C^{n\times n}$, then $x_{kk}=\frac{\det B_{k+1,n}}{\det B_{kn}} \quad and \quad x_{nn} = 1/a_{nn},$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Show that if $ A \in \mathbb C^{n\times n}$, then

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
    a_{kk}  & \cdots &a_{kn} \\
    \vdots & \cdots & \vdots \\
    a_{nk}& \cdots & a_{nn}
    \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
    x_{kk} \\
    \vdots \\
    x_{nk} \\
    \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    0 \\
    \vdots \\
    0 \\
    \end{bmatrix} \quad \text{ for } \quad k=1,...,n \quad (1)$$

then
$x_{kk}=\frac{\det B_{k+1,n}}{\det B_{kn}} \quad \text{ for } \quad k=1,...,n-1 \quad \text{ and }\quad x_{nn} = 1/a_{nn},$

Where $B_{kn}$ denotes the inverse of the matrix that is displayed in $(1)$.

**Note:** I've solved the previous two exercises which should help me in this one, and I'm stil struggling to show $(1)$, and that the subsequent variables $x_{kk},x_{nn}$ values are as mentioned.

The previous two exercises are as follows:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem statement is wrong. E.g. consider
$$
Ax=\pmatrix{1&1\\ 1&2}\pmatrix{2\\ -1}=\pmatrix{1\\ 0}
$$
with $B_{12}=A^{-1}$ and $B_{22}=(a_{22})^{-1}=\frac12$. Then $\frac{\det(B_{22})}{\det(B_{12})}=\frac{1/2}{1}\ne2=x_1$.

The correct statement should be $x_1=\frac{\det(A_{k+1})}{\det(A_{k})}=\frac{\det(B_{kn})}{\det(B_{k+1,n})}$, where $A_k$ denotes the trailing principal matrix taken from the $k$-th up to the last rows/columns of $A$. This is a direct consequence of Cramer's rule.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: @user2323232 Solve (1) by Cramer's rule.

Comment: Hi @user1551, thanks for the hint, can you please show it explicitly? I wasn't able to successfully apply Cramer's rule on (1) yet. I wrote $(1)$ as linear equations, then I took $x_kk$ and wrote it as fraction of two determinants, where in the denominator it's the matrix in $(1)$ and in the nominator I just replaced the vector of $[1,0,...,]$ just in the first column and the other columns are as in the matrix as $(1)$, but how can I rephrase is at $B_{k,n}$ and $B_{k+1,n}$ to show it's identical?

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS It seems that the numerator and denominator in the ratio of determinants were mistakenly swapped in the problem statement.

Comment: Yeah, I just showed that, will upload my solution later. Thank you.